# Reference amp-bind-macro IDs to execute expression

Tags: html, expression, amp-bind

I'm trying to reference an amp-bind-macro expression (I need to use different amp-bind-expressions depending on user inputs).

Trouble is, when I try to reference them, it doesn't execute the expression. In the console it says syntax error. No matter what I try I can't get it working.

Here's an example of the code I'm trying to implement:

```
<amp-bind-macro id="exampleMacro" arguments="input" expression="8*input"></amp-bind-macro>

<amp-state id="exampleJson">
<script type="application/json">
 { "test": "exampleMacro" }
</script>
</amp-state>

<span [text]="[exampleJson.test](input)">0.0</span>
```

I've tried:

```
<span [text]="exampleJson.test(input)">0.0</span>
<span [text]="[exampleJson.test][(input)]">0.0</span>
```

Any ideas team?
The AMP documentation says:
"A macro can be invoked like a function by referencing its id attribute value from anywhere in your doc"
https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-bind?referrer=ampproject.org#defining-macros-with-amp-bind-macro

So I would have thought it was possible to do this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the example in the documentation link shows, `amp-bind-macro` can only be referenced by `id` in amp-bind expressions. E.g.

```html
<span [text]="exampleMacro()">0.0</span>
```

Hope that helps!